# How to run html in own windows window?

Tags: browser

I need some simple solution to run database program (php, html, javascript, jquery) in own window. So u click on desktop icon and it open program window and html content, u do not see internet browser logo and other elements. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)? Why don't you want to use a browser?

Comment: You need to develop your own browser :)  With Win8 i have develop a app with c# and there are a webview, which only show what i like. Your browser need to interpret javascript and html and all the other stuff. Its not made in a hour

Answer (score 1):

You have to develop a windows application using visual studio or any other tool in which you have to take webview element to show your contents.